# $p$ value for a randomized test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

For a randomized test, how do we compute the $p$-value?
For example, suppose the test is of the form:
$\phi(X)=1$ if $X > c$, $\phi(X)=p$ when $X=c$ and $\phi(X)=0$ otherwise.
How do we compute the $p$ value?

Comment: Are you referring to a randomized controlled trial? Or are you referring to a randomiz*ation* test, aka permutation test?

Comment: @AdamO It is really a *randomized* test: the decision rule is not deterministic. If $X>c$ is observed, we reject $H_0$, if $X < c$ then we don't reject, but if $X=c$, then we reject with some probability $p$. This can be useful when the test statistic is discrete to achieve a type I error exactly equal to the preset $\alpha$.

Comment: I have not heard of p-values in this context. Since $p$ is selected to set the size of the test to $\alpha$, and the p-value is essentially the significance level at which one would just reject the observed test statistic, I guess you would need to specify how $p$ is selected as a function of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I encountered this "size-correction" approach to NHST in my theory class, so that the size of significance tests is equal to the level. I'll note this isn't popular in practice, and conservative tests (like the Fisher's Exact Test), are never given any randomized correction.

Comment: There is a connection with the concept of *mid-p* value